# Função do javascript não está trocando o window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, node.js

Criei uma função para pesquisa simples, conforme o código abaixo

```js
function pesquisar(){
 var pesquisa = document.getElementById('pesquisa').value
 window.location.pathname = 'produtos'
 window.location.search = 'pesquisa=' + pesquisa
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 order-2 order-md-1 site-search-icon text-left">
  <form action="javascript:pesquisar()" class="site-block-top-search">
    <span class="icon icon-search2"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Pesquisar" id="pesquisa">
  </form>
</div>
```

Isto até funciona para trocar o  valor do search, porém o valor do pathname não está sendo alterado

Quando o comando é digitado diretamente no console do navegador, está executando perfeitamente

Alguem saberia um possível motivo?

```
@EDIT
```

Caso seja util, segue abaixo o backend da aplicação

```js
router.get('/produtos', function (req, res) {
    if(req.query.pesquisa){
        resultado = {nome: new RegExp(req.query.pesquisa, 'i')}
    }else{
        resultado = {}
    }
    _produto.paginate(resultado, { limit: 21, page: req.query.pag, sort: {nome: 'asc', cadastro: 'desc'} }, function (err, res) {
        if (!res.page) {
            res.page = 1
            res.nextPage = 2
            res.hasPrevPage = false
            res.hasNextPage = true
        } 
        return res
        
    }).then(function (produto) {
        res.render('produtos', { produto: produto.docs, pag: produto })
    })
})
```

Comment: Olá José? Onde tem node.js aí? O que você quer fazer exatamente? Pois um formulário muda a URL via atributo action; se você usar get, a sua variável já vai ser passada. Se você utilizar a pesquisa por ajax, você precisa prevenir o browser de recarregar com prevent default e coletar os dados, onde mudar URL é só um passo para isso. Por último, conhece JQuery?

Comment: Bom dia, estou estudando ainda,  já fiz o backend da aplicação, porém não conheço boas práticas para realizar algumas ações como pesquisa por exemplo, e como estou estudando prefiro criar minhas próprias maneiras para fazer as ações, atualmente consigo fazer a pesquisa digitando na url, sendo assim preciso apenas alterar a url quando o usuario digitar o que deseja no input, já edito o post e incluo a parte do backend

Comment: Lembrando também, que o motivo de colocar /produtos é apenas para redirecionar para a página correta no momento da pesquisa, caso o usuário esteja em outra página na minha aplicação, irei continuar tentando, e enviarei atualizações caso consiga algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende o navegador que está usando, há problema de compatibilidade, veja tabela aqui:

[pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)

No momento dessa resposta, **Edge** e **Opera** não são compatívies.
Além disso, o pathname contém a barra "/", e seu código de exemplo não tem, precisa corrigir isso também, veja o exemplo aqui do SO mesmo:

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname);
```

**EDIT** também notei no seu código que está usando uma action javascript no *form*, e action deve ser usado para informar uma url, não uma function, nesse caso deveria usar o evento "onsubit", assim por exemplo:

```
<form class="site-block-top-search" action="#" onsubmit="pesquisar();">
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo, agradeço a resposta, já havia tentado com a / e sem a barra, porém o problema persistiu, atualmente utilizo o chrome na versão 75.0.3770.90 (Mais recente até o momento da resposta), então creio que o problema seja realmente algo diferente

Comment: então não deve ser um problema de compatibilidade.. editei a pergunta e inclui mais um detalhe sobre a forma como está fazendo o submit, veja se ajuda

Comment: Antes de ter o problema descrito, havia tentado desta forma, porém parece que o action estava substituindo o "location.search", então optei por remover submit e usei apenas o action para executar a função, se eu uso esta forma a resposta que recebo na url é: "?#", isso com a url da pagina que fiz a pesquisa, se eu fizer a pesquisa diretamente da pagina de produtos recebo http://localhost/produtos?#, como não obtive sucesso nas minhas tentativas irei realizar a consulta pelo backend da aplicação, utilizando um get, creio que seja um bug no js